# A good term describing the dichotomy between stochastic and deterministic?

Tags: word-choice

I'm searching for a fine **word-choice for X in: "The X of the model outputs can be deterministic or stochastic."**:

I know that we can write that the

- **Size** of a house is *small* or *large*
- **Color** of a car is *black* or *red*
- **Your Attitude** may be *kind* or *mean*

But what is, in a similar vein, **a good term to use for X when I want to write that**

> **"The **X** of the model outputs can be *deterministic* or *stochastic*."**

I could simply write "nature" for **X**, but that would be unsuitable when I want to use the word separately to just mention the dichotomy explicitly.

Another word I could imagine is "epistemic nature", but I'm not sure that would be legit/understandable at all.

Comment: What is the context for this statement? A scientific experiment? Philosophical thought? I'd presume the former but it would be good to be sure.

Comment: @dweeblet Context is a scientific presentation on forecasting methods. Forecasts can differ along various dimensions, and the "X" is one of these dimensions.

Comment: I think that this type of question should belong on English Language and Usage SE.

Comment: @Nai45 I hesitated to do that before I posted here; the purpose/condition description of English Language and Usage ES though was making me more reluctant to put it there eventually.

Comment: @niamulbengali Good to know. Not sure now whether good to duplicate the question thus.

Comment: What is the difference between *"**The X of the model** outputs can be deterministic or stochastic."* and "***The model** outputs can be deterministic or stochastic."*? The predicate of the verb to be speaks of the subject's attributes, nature, etc

Comment: @Greybeard The sentence could readily be stated the way you propose. I added the X just so I can have a placeholder to illustrate what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the process :

> The **generation** of the model outputs can be deterministic or stochastic.

You could be referring to what is generated such as:

> The **values** of the model outputs can be deterministic or stochastic.

Similarly if you really want to focus in on outputs as a whole:

> The **distribution** of the model outputs can be deterministic or stochastic.

Keep in mind this is about what you want to communicate. So it's all about what this sentence is trying to support.

Comment: "Distribution" comes closest to meet my needs.

Answer (score 1):

How about **domain** ? I suppose this word is often used in mathematical parlance when suggesting a range of values.

> The domain of model outputs can be deterministic or stochastic.

Comment: I quite like the suggestion. Not 100% sure yet it's the least unideal. Remains very general too. E.g.: My model outputs tend to be future forecasts, often time-series; `domain` could well be understood as relating to time-series instead (just one example that comes to mind).

Answer (score 0):

The closest word I can think of that fits your criterium is etiology. Etiology is the study of causation, so you could argue that the things causing the outputs are deterministic or or stochastic:

> The etiology of the model outputs can be deterministic or stochastic.

Comment: Thanks. It is a term I had never heard before, which itself makes me a bit hesitant, although you might be right that there is nothing better available.